# Run the file in remote PC without disclosing the username and password

Tags: vb.net, powershell, batch-file, remote-access

I am trying to create an executable file which can run the bat file in the remote PC for automation. This executable file will be given to non admin users to do specific tasks at the remote PC.

I found that there are 2 ways to connect remotely by storing the credentials and by giving the credentials upon connection. I can’t do the second option because I can’t present every time they connect. So I need to save the password somewhere they can’t find. I used tools like psexcec and the problem is that anyone can see the password in process viewer when the psexcec runs.

Is there any way that I can run the file in the remote PC disclosing the credentials? In batch file, powershell, .NET any of this is fine. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Blegh... Depends what level of security we're talking about here. A standard exe (eg built in C# with Visual Studio Express) can be decompiled pretty easily but perhaps that would work for you? Otherwise you would need to look at paid stuff to obfuscate the exe so it's harder to decompile.